# convert a date to a %Y:%j:%H:%M:%s in python with date command

Tags: python, date, datetime

I'm trying to convert a series of dates in python 2.6.6 with os.popen and the date command using the following call:

```
    t=wp.time
    dtme=os.popen("date -d t +%Y:%j:%H:%M:%S")
    dtime=dtme.read()
```

Where wp.time is a series of dates in the following format:

2014-07-22 19:59:53

The issue with date command is it seems to be having trouble reading the space in between the date and the yyyy-mm-dd. Is there a work around for this?  What am I doing wrong in python when I do this? Is there a better way to do this? My datetime.strptime doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: If it helps I think the issue is it doesn't like the space. It complains about the extra operand. If there's a way to do this in more steps I am open too.

Comment: What do you mean by **My datetime.strptime doesn't seem to be working.**? The code above doesn't include a call to `datetime.strptime`.

Comment: `os.popen` appears to be deprecated

Comment: I mean that I tried it and it throws an error. I am using python 2.6.6, is it deprecated since that version. Anything to replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%j`  doesn't look right for *reading* the date format you want, that's for day of year format.

I think for strptime or strftime, you want

> "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s"

as your format string for something like 2014-07-22 19:59:53

Also the Linux date command would be

> echo `date +"%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S"`

Or if I misunderstood you and you want to convert *to* day of year format, this code snippet will do it:

```
import datetime

t = "2014-07-22 19:59:53"
thedatetime= datetime.datetime.strptime(t,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
my_new_t =datetime.datetime.strftime(thedatetime,"%Y:%j %H:%M:%S")
print 'my_new_t',my_new_t
```

Output is

> my_new_t 2014:203 19:59:53

If you want the semicolon in the output, no space do

```
my_new_t =datetime.datetime.strftime(thedatetime,"%Y:%j:%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: what does, the os.popen? I'm a bit confused, if you already have date strings why use os.popen to convert them?

Comment: When I run the datetime.datetime.strptime commands in your third gray box. I am trying to convert the date to yyyy/mm/dd to day of year. And attach the H:M:S onto it. So I want 2014-07-22 19:59:53 to be 2014:203:19:59:53. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I'm running this code (third box) successfully now and it produces the output you want (fourth box) if you **import datetime** and call **datetime.datetime.strptime** (with two datetime). @Mark is using different but also valid import syntax **from datetime import datetime** so he calls **datetime.strptime** (one datetime)

Comment: I know but your t is a string and mine isn't. Can I convert it to a string somehow?

Comment: Ah, OK. You said your t=wp.time. Of what type is that? I thought it was a string formatted like 2014-07-22 19:59:53

Comment: Nevermind, I just used str to convert it and it worked out :) Thanks paisanco!

Answer (score 2):

Just use `datetime.strptime`.  It is not deprecated, and it works:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> t='2014-07-22 19:59:53'
>>> datetime.strptime(t,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 22, 19, 59, 53)
```

Note that there is a `datetime` *class* and a `datetime` *module*.  That is likely the cause of the error you reported:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime
<built-in method strptime of type object at 0x1E200528>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) library. It contains specific advice about how to replace `os.popen()` calls